# how to insert into arraylist using a scanner?

Tags: java, insert, arraylist, mergesort, insertion-sort

I'm having some problems trying to figure out how to insert an integer using a scanner into an ArrayList. I'm not that great (actually not even really good) at java but I'm just trying to figure some things out and any help would be great.

```
package mySort;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class MergeInsert {
private int limit = 100;
//private int size = 0;
private ArrayList<Integer> ArrayToSort;

public MergeInsert(int x) {
    ArrayToSort = new ArrayList<Integer>(x);
    }

public MergeInsert(Scanner integerScan){
    int j = 0;
    while(integerScan.hasNextInt()){
        this.insert(integerScan.hasNextInt());
        if (j % 10000 == 0){
            long time = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println(j + "," + time);
        }
    }
}

public void insert(int x){
    for(int i=0; i<ArrayToSort.size(); i++){
        ArrayToSort(size++) = x;
    }
}


//  public MergeInsert(int v){
//      int val = v;
//  }

//    public void insertFile(){
//      try {
//          Scanner integerScan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(""));
//          while(integerScan.hasNextInt()){
//              new MergeInsert(integerScan.nextInt());
//          }
//      }
//       catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
//    }


public void sort(){

}

public void mergeSort(ArrayList<Integer> in, int low,int high){
    int n = in.size();
    int mid = (high+low)/2;
    if (n<2){  //already sorted
        return;
    }
    if ((high - low) < limit){
        insertionSort(in);
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> in1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //helper
    ArrayList<Integer> in2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //helper
    int i=0;

    while (i < n/2){ //moves the first half to the helper
        in1.add(in.remove(0));
        i++;
    }
    while (!in.isEmpty()) //moves the second half to the helper
        in2.add(in.remove(0));
    mergeSort(in1, low, mid); //breaks it down some more like mergesort should
    mergeSort(in2, mid+1, high); //does it again
    merge(in1,in2,in); //trying to build it up again
    }

public void merge(ArrayList<Integer> in, ArrayList<Integer> in1, ArrayList<Integer> in2){
    while (!in1.isEmpty() || !in2.isEmpty()) //as long as both helpers still have elements
        if ((in1.get(0).compareTo(in2.get(0)) <= 0)) //comparison to rebuild
            in.add(in1.remove(0)); //building it back up
        else
            in.add(in2.remove(0)); //still building
    while(!in1.isEmpty()) //as long as the first helper isn't empty keep building
        in.add(in1.remove(0));
    while(!in2.isEmpty()) //as long as the second helper isn't empty keep building
        in.add(in2.remove(0));
}

public ArrayList<Integer> insertionSort(ArrayList<Integer> in){
    int index = 1;
    while (index<in.size()){
        insertSorted((int)(in.get(index)),in,index);
        index = index +1;
    }
    return in;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> insertSorted(Integer s, ArrayList<Integer> in, int index){
    int loc = index-1;
    while((loc>=0) || s.compareTo(in.get(loc)) <= 0){
        in.set(loc + 1, in.get(loc));
        loc = loc -1;
    }
    in.set(loc+1, s);
    return in;
    }


/**
 * @param args
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner integerScan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("src/myRandomNumbers.txt"));
    MergeInsert myObject = new MergeInsert(integerScan);
    myObject.sort();

}

}
```

It's not completely finished but the idea behind all of this is to try and improve on MergeSort. Basically once the elements get broken down to a certain point cut to InsertionSort because it is usually better on really small (really small being relative) sets of data.

Comment: As a side note, your threshold for going to insertion sort instead of merge sort is REALLY high. In the JDK, it's 7. You have it at 100. :-O

Comment: I was just using it as a place holder for the time being. I was going to run it on different sized lists to see what would be best for different sized sets.

Comment: Profiling and adjusting constants is the best way to do it! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void insert(int x){
    ArrayToSort.add(x); // add it to the end
}
```

The reason is... even if you go

```
ArrayToSort = new ArrayList<Integer>(100000);
```

It still  has a size of 0. It just has a CAPACITY of 100000.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot I added the size reference in there. I was just trying to see if that helped before posting, obviously didn't.

Comment: If you don't provide a size, it just does `new ArrayList<Integer>(10)` instead. You can override the default of 10 if you want.

Comment: Don't ArrayLists expand as needed during run-time? Like if I'm reading in 1000 elements it will expand to hold them and if I read in from a different file with 1 million it should handle that as well without any modification to code. Or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. But, if you KNOW you're going to be getting at least a certain amount of records, why not save yourself a couple expansions that you don't need to do? By default, it's 10, so it will expand at 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 640, 1280, 2560, 5120, 10240, 20480, 40960, 81920, 163840, 327680, and 655360. So that's 16 expansions you simply don't need to do if you're know you'll get 1000000 records. If you -don't- preallocate, it will still work just fine, it will just be a tad slower.

Comment: Okay, got it, thanks. I didn't know that all it did was double in size all the time. Should definitely help things run a little bit faster if I did override that. Since I am trying to make it go faster in the first place then that would only make sense to do it that way.

Comment: Right. But it can be bad. If you allocate 1000000 in size, but you only use 24... that's a lot of wasted memory! You can also use a `trimToSize()` when it's done growing.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`add`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) to insert objects into the list.

Also, the way your code is structured now, you will get a `NullPointerException` when you attempt to invoke `add` because the constructor you invoke never initializes the list.

Given the quality of your code, I highly recommend reading [Learning the Java Language](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).